# How do I uninstall Unity 8 from my desktop computer?

Tags: uninstall, unity8

Since [Unity 8 is now being discontinued](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2017/04/05/growing-ubuntu-for-cloud-and-iot-rather-than-phone-and-convergence/), how do I uninstall it from my desktop system?

(Please note: This question is *not* about Unity 7, which is still supported at the time of this writing and should remain installed if present.)

Comment: I deleted my answer below. Thanks for helping me understand the differences between Unity 8 preview based on Unity 7.5 and Unity 8 which was cancelled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fully remove Unity 8 from your system running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS or later, follow these instructions:

1. Open a new Terminal window, and enter the following command (providing your password if requested):

   ```
   sudo apt purge unity8 ubuntu-system-settings
   ```
2. After the previous command finishes, you may also enter this command to remove all of the unneeded packages that Unity 8 left behind for a cleaner system:

   ```
   sudo apt autoremove
   ```
3. Reboot your computer to finish the uninstallation process.

(Source: [OMG! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/04/uninstall-unity-8-ubuntu))